# How to create groups and assign users to them?

Tags: 7

I want to allow the administrator and manager roles to be able to create groups (for example different jobs within a company) and be able to assign users to the groups. I want this to be a one-to-many relationship so that user1 can be assigned to job1 and job2 (or no job) but user1 can't be assigned twice to the same job.

How would I go about starting this or what is a good module and/or resource to utilize?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like a clear use case for the [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og) module. Organic Groups is great if you have a need to create a container for content and then associate users with that container.

However, if you don't have a need for any content-oriented aspects of OG (such as access control), then maybe all you need to do is make the associations visible, rather than a part of the site's information architecture. In that case, it sounds like you might want to use the [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) so you can leverage [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) Node Reference fields, which can be one:many arrangements, and using the bundled content_permissions module or [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions), restricted to roles with specific permissions for editing the field.